# how to packaging jar file and mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, database, jar

I created a java desktop application by using net beans 8.0 and MySQL as database i connected database through local host 3306 . I make the jar file by clean and build . the jar file is work fine in my computer but when i moved the jar file to my friends computer is not work I Install MySQL in his computer so I get massage that say there is no table so how i can packaging the MySQL database with jar file I will appreciate any help.

i use that code to connect data base

```
cons = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/monl", "root", "zain");
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you actually created the table on his instance of MySql? You could execute a query to create the table if it does not exist, so you're guaranteed you're not trying to access a non-existent table. You'll have to explicitly create the table on his machine.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

Comment: thank for replying i have create table in my device which is a password table so because i am new to this i want to ask you does the database transfer to other device

Comment: No, it does not: the database will not transfer, and it should be created seperately on the other machine. You'll be running seperate instances, unless you're running MySQL on a remote host and both connect to it.

Comment: so how i can let the user log in

Comment: In order to let other users connect to your database, you will have to replace "localhost" in the connection URL by your IP address, and forward port 3306 to the machine running MySQL.

Comment: is there any way to connect database with out sharing through remote host  by using any other database